# alternative to eulerproject.net in regarding to computer science algorithms

Tags: algorithm, computer-science

On eulerproject.net the context is mainly related to mathematics.

Is there a website for practising (and solving) common issues of algorithms, which are non-mathematical?
I am talking about issues e.g. NP-hard problems or good strategies for efficient data handling (divide+conquer, dictionaries..).

Thanks for every helpful answer in advance.

Kind regards

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Project Rosalind](http://rosalind.info) has a good selection of problems relating to bioinformatics algorithms.

[Hackerrank](https://www.hackerrank.com) has a choice of problems in categories including NP-complete, Dynamic programming, Graph theory.

Answer (score 0):

you can find problems on [topcoder](http://community.topcoder.com/tc)
and [there](http://www.codechef.com/problems/easy/)